# What would be a good way to loop all images in a folder in React?

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app

I have some images in a folder and I try to loop it. For example, a folder named "coupons" has some images like "coupon1.png","coupon2.png","coupon3.png"....
Then in one component, I try to make a function to import all the images and return

```js
<img src={coupon1} alt='coupon1' className="slide" />
<img src={coupon2} alt='coupon2' className="slide" />
<img src={coupon3} alt='coupon3' className="slide" />
.....
```

May I know what would be a good way to do this?  How to avoid import images one by one? And how to get the total number of the images files in the folder?

```
import coupon1 from '../assets/coupons/coupon1.png';
import coupon2 from '../assets/coupons/coupon2.png';
import coupon3 from '../assets/coupons/coupon3.png';
...
```

And how to loop them? I tried to use template string but it ends with string not variable so still not work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

1) You can use webpack and generate alias with file list.

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const child_process = require('child_process');
let stdout = child_process.execSync("find . -regex  '.*\\(png\\|jgeg\\)$'", {encoding: 'utf8'});
let files = stdout.split('\n');


module.exports = {
    plugins = [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            IMAGES: JSON.stringify(files),
        }),
    ];
}
```

**index.js**:

```
Promise.all(
    files.map(a => import(a))
).then(
    filesSources => console.log(`DO something with array: ${filesSources}`)
);
```

2) You can require images with context:

**index.js**:

```
list = require.context('./', false, /\.(png|jpeg)$/);
```

3) You can use copyWebpackPLugin if you don't need to work with sources:

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {from: './src/assets/images', to: 'images'},
 ]),
```

Note in 3) case image won't be processed by webpack loaders chain. In first 2 cases you need to add rule for FileLoader. You can find example of 3 cases at https://github.com/akoidan/pychat/tree/master/fe

Comment: Thank you so much! May I know how to get the total number of image files in a folder?

Comment: `array.length`?)

Comment: Thank you! So import all the images in an array then use .length right?

Comment: const slides = Array(6).fill().map((item, i) => (
            <img key={i} src={require(`../assets/coupons/coupon${i + 1}.png`)} className="slide" />
        )); May I know what does require here means? Is it also from webpack? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Oh and I just found a way like this:

```js
const slides = Array(6).fill().map((item, i) => (
            <img key={i} src={require(`../assets/coupons/coupon${i + 1}.png`)} className="slide" />
        ));
```

but I'm not sure is this a good way to do this? And what is this syntax of using require inside jsx? May I know is there any explanation about why using require here?

Comment: Does it work? only dynamic imports can be inside of scope (of a function)

Comment: @deathangel908 Yeah it works but I don't know why we use require here? I thought require is a nodejs or webpack way? And may I know is there a way to get the files number in this way? So I don't need to use Array(certain number).fill(). Thank you so much

Comment: No node is run here. Node only powers webpack, webpack doesn't run your source files, it only processes them. What it means webpack uses commonJs resolution strategy by default, note it's not related to ES6/TS/ES3 syntaxt (import/require etc). What it exactly does it looks up for requires inside your source code and makes webpack-modules from them, running them through loaders before it.